# Gstreamer or VLC? For desktop and mobile platforms?

Tags: java, android, c, gstreamer, vlc

Is there any cross platform binaries available for Gstreamer to install it via Web start or Jnlp?

Such as VLC seems almost have all platform compatibility but it does not provide Gst and commands are completely different.

$gst-inspect filesrc missing
$gst-inspect sdp missing
$gst-inspect other codecs missing
- lot of missing in other platforms or its bug in other platforms?

note: I need to port Gstreamer from Linux working model to **Iphone, Nokia, Blackberry, Symbian, Atom machine, Arm processors, Ipad, Meego, Windows/Mac/Bsd**. Alternative of Gstreamer in such wide crossplatform is also a choice to ignore using Gstreamer, its good but very small future. Also the community seems dont have any action to make it happen, so as a developer it looks like loneliness in the big world

Comment: Whoa there - every platform you mention has some kind of media playback framework, are you sure you are not [shaving the yak](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html)?

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos: excuse me? Do you know what is the differences between having a Framework and not having a framework for wide cross platform? ex: QT, WxWidget, Zend framework, Cakephp, Ruby rails, Jboss etc etc? Or better doing it from ZERO?

Comment: Let me rephrase my objection in another way - it is going to be easier to implement a framework that abstracts away the platform details for media playback than porting gstreamer to all these platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want pre-made crossplatform binaries of GStreamer the simplest solution is to get the Media SDK from Entropy Wave:

http://entropywave.com/products/entropy-wave-media-sdk/

Comment: its very nice somebody is doing this atleast. But any FREE community who can also offer such?